# CERTENROLLLib alternatives in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I would like to decode Certificate Requests PCKS #10 to obtain all necessary information such Common Name, Key Length and most important Subject Alternate Names.

Previously on .Net WebFroms I used CERTENROLLLib library and CX509ExtensionAlternativeNames/CX509CertificateRequestPkcs10 classes. Now I'm looking for replacement in .Net Core

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

Neither .NET Core nor .NET Framework has built-in support for reading PKCS#10 blobs / certificate signing requests.  You'll need to use a 3rd party library (Portable.BouncyCastle might work, and might have what you need), or read [RFC 2986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986) and parse the data yourself.

If you don't know how to read DER encoded data, [ITU X.680](http://www.itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=X.680) will explain the ASN.1 syntax:

```
CertificationRequestInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    version       INTEGER { v1(0) } (v1,...),
    subject       Name,
    subjectPKInfo SubjectPublicKeyInfo{{ PKInfoAlgorithms }},
    attributes    [0] Attributes{{ CRIAttributes }}
}
```

And [ITU X.690](http://www.itu.int/itu-t/recommendations/rec.aspx?rec=X.690) will explain how the structures from ASN.1 are encoded under the Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER).

Comment: Is it now supported with this PR https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/20887?

Comment: @nemke no, that added the ability to create PKCS#10 requests, not to read them in.