# .Net Core CertificateRequest as parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core, x509certificate2, .net-standard-2.0

As Authority Center I want to be able to receive [CertificateRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.certificaterequest?view=netcore-2.1), basically, WebApi POST action  that get the CertificateRequest as a parameter, as a client ( http/https client that send CertificateRequest to sign it by CA certificate pvk) I have 2 difficulties if use .Net Standard 2.0. Firstly this object seems to be only in next release ( already exit in .Net Core 2.1 not in standard) and the second that this object is not serializable ( so basically I couldn't pass it as a parameter). Is it possible somehow to implement with .Net Standard 2.x ?

Comment: Unfortunately, `CertificateRequest` class cannot decode existing requests. You have to use 3rd party libraries for this.

Comment: @Crypt32 thanks, but I think that most of them are based on that CertificateRequest class and will not provide more than some wrapper.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853913/certenrolllib-alternatives-in-net-core